# Change the textwidth in a graphic caption?

Tags: floats, indentation

Following a minimal code from somebody who asked why it produces a longer line for caption text of the figure, than a line in the main text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,latexsym,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[dvips,dvipdf]{graphicx,color}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.0in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.25in} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.09in}

\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 


\begin{figure}[h,t,b]
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{b.eps}
\caption{The triangular lattice with faces labelled as close-packed (C) and empty (O), the corresponding planar modification, and its generator.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I failed to reproduce the problem he has. But I think the solution may be to set up the textwidth for the figure caption, to match it with the textwidth in the main text.

So I wonder how to set the textwidth for the figure caption?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `floatrow` package and set wider margins for the floating environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\setfloatmargins{\hspace{-0.5in}}{\hspace{-0.5in}}

\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa


\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{b.eps}

\caption{The triangular lattice with faces labelled as close-packed (C) and empty (O),
the corresponding planar modification, and its generator.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've used the `demo` option just to provide a mock illustration, don't use it yourself. Note however that `latexsym` is obsolete and `amssymb` should be used instead (which loads `amsfonts`). Also the options `dvips` and `dvipdf` shouldn't be passed to `graphicx` or `color`.

The positioning specifier can be `[htb]`, without commas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What do the two parameters in `\setfloatmargins{\hspace{-0.5in}}{\hspace{-0.5in}}
` man?

Comment: @Tim They are the amounts by which the horizontal space is enlarged at the left and at the right. Choose your own.